# Datalogging from Arduino Mega to Dropbox

Tags: arduino, gps

I have an Arduino Mega board and the Adafruit Ultimate GPS Logger + GPS module shield. I have these two connected together using headers and have the entire thing mounted on my drone. Currently, I have a code that I found online and modified slightly to get GPS coordinates in NMEA format and parse them for the information I actually want. I can store these in an SD card.

The thing is, I want to use the Arduino GSM shield to somehow send this data, either from the SD card or directly, to a folder in Dropbox. I have no idea how to do that, if it's possible at all. I just started working with Arduino about a month ago, so I apologize if my question sounds particularly noob-ish.

Could anyone on this forum at least guide me on how to approach this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check out this [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Datalogging-to-Dropbox-with-Arduino-Yun/) to get some ideas.  Basically the general setup is it uses the [Dropbox Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core) and a OS/Python capable board, which in the case of the aforementioned link is the Arduino Yun.

Comment: @jrcatbagan It's using Linux and Wifi. I want to use Windows and GPS. Will that make a difference? I'm thinking of using the Arduino GSM module (which is supposed to be available on the 25th of March).